# CakePHP: What is the correct format for saving data in a HABTM

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have an artist that has and belongs to many related artists, in this example i want to save  Madonna and her 2 related artists Cher and Kylie Minogue in the database.

DB:
**2 tables:** artists (id, name, created) and artists_related (id, artist_id, related_id)

Model relationship setup:

```
<?php
class Artist extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Related' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Artist',
                'joinTable' => 'artists_related',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'related_id',
                'unique' => 'keepExisting'
            )
        );
```

I'm trying to save the data like this:

```
    $test_data = array(
        'Artist' => array(
            'name' => 'Madonna'
         ),
        'Related' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => 'Kylie Minogue'
            ),
            1 => array(
                'name' => 'Cher'
            )
        )
    );

    $result = $this->saveAll($test_data, array('deep' => true));
```

What happens is that only Madonna is saved in the **artists** table, the two related artists arent saved, and nothing is saved in the join table.

How should the data array be formatted to accomplish this? Or do i need to save first Madonna, and get the id and then save all the related artists in a different saveAll() ?

Answer (score 2):

As I know the **related artist** must contain **Related** Object that have key **Related** with some **artist_id**. This is example:

```
$test_data = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'name' => 'Madonna'
     ),
    'Related' => array(
         'Related' => array(
             0 => '1',
             1 => '2'
         )
     )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You data has to be in this format.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        ['Artist'] => Array
            (
                [name] => 'Madonna'
            )
        ['Related'] => Array
            (
                [name] => 'Kylie Minogue'
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        ['Artist'] => Array
            (
                [name] => 'Madonna'
            )
        ['Related'] => Array
            (
                [name] => 'Cher'
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't think so: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That looks very strange but i tried it anyway. The result is that Madonna was inserted in the **artists** table twice. Kylie and Cher was not, and nothing was inserted in the join table.

Comment: do you have primary key ids, if so those have to be included.

Comment: No primary key ids because none of these has been saved before. Another option i have been playing with is to save Madonna first, get the id, and then save all the related artists after.